# why doesn't recieved for Wallet.Payments.loadMaskedWallet in judo android pay?

Tags: android, android-pay

I try android judopay in android app.

1.my phone was unrooted.

2.Android pay app is installed on my phone and register card.

3.Apk is published on google play and I created Oauth certificate with signed APK's sha1

4.i used below code.

```
private void createWalletFragment() {
    WalletFragmentStyle walletStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
            .setBuyButtonText(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonText.LOGO_ONLY)
            .setBuyButtonAppearance(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonAppearance.ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT_WITH_BORDER)
            .setBuyButtonWidth(WalletFragmentStyle.Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);

    WalletFragmentOptions options = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
            .setEnvironment(ENVIRONMENT)
            .setFragmentStyle(walletStyle)
            .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_DARK)
            //.setMode(WalletFragmentMode.SELECTION_DETAILS)
            .build();

    PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters parameters = PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
            .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.NETWORK_TOKEN)
            .addParameter("publicKey", getString(R.string.public_key))
            .build();

    walletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(options);

    MaskedWalletRequest walletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()
            .setMerchantName(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setCurrencyCode(CURRENCY)
            .setEstimatedTotalPrice(AMOUNT)
            .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(parameters)
            .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
                    .setCurrencyCode(CURRENCY)
                    .setTotalPrice(AMOUNT)
                    .build())
            .build();

    WalletFragmentInitParams startParams = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
            .setMaskedWalletRequest(walletRequest)
            .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST)
            .build();      
    //skip purchase button process
     Wallet.Payments.loadMaskedWallet (googleApiClient, walletRequest ,MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST);
}
```

Already googleapiclient is checked,and i call loadMaskedWallet function succesfully.

But i can never received any response on onActivityResult() function.

why doesn't recieved for Wallet.Payments.loadMaskedWallet in judo android pay?

Comment: Please post the whole code and also any errors that happen or the relevant logs.

Comment: I can not share full source because of business.Would you let me know another mode?